# Slow git on Mac OS X server: can it be helped?

Tags: ssh, git, mac-osx-server

We've been running git over SSH on our Mac OS X server. (It happens to be a Mini.) Problem is, it's frightfully slow. We often see speeds under 100KiB/s for cloning repositories *from* this server, and similar speeds cloning repositories from elsewhere *to* this server. The issue is not the server or its network connection; we've run speed tests and seen 1.5 to 2MB/s download speeds and up to 7MB/s upload. `scp` transfers of large files are similarly quick.

Our theory is that git is moving a ton of tiny files, and this is causing filesystem overhead which is slowing the transfer.

- Is this a reasonable theory?
- Is there anything we can do to improve git performance on this box, or should we be looking for alternative hosting for our git repositories?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your theory sounds likely if your git repo contains a lot of small files.
On a single disk, with no hardware acceleration (SSD), you will probably see a tps of two digits at most in `iostat`.

Gather some data to help verify or falsify your theory.

```
  # iostat -d 1
      disk0           disk1           disk2
  KB/t tps  MB/s     KB/t tps  MB/s     KB/t tps  MB/s
   64.41  23  1.43    90.38  11  1.01   581.67   0  0.02
   20.00   2  0.04     0.00   0  0.00     0.00   0  0.00
  265.33   3  0.78     0.00   0  0.00     0.00   0  0.00
```